# JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available

Tags: spring-boot, deployment, java-8, jboss, jboss6.x

I have an issue about jboss eap 6.4 and Spring Boot application. I have two standalone in jboss. We are running several IVR application as war. When i deployed Spring Boot application as war. It was deployed. But When I send request this error occurs:

`JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 404 - /ivr-adapter-0.0.1/error
JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000067: Status report

JBWEB000068: message /ivr-adapter-0.0.1/error

JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available.

JBoss Web/7.5.7.Final-redhat-1`

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.22.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.assistt</groupId>
    <artifactId>ivr-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>ivr-adapter</name>
    <description>IVR Adapter</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvoicexml</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.jvoicexml</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

One of the my controller:

```
package com.assistt.ivradapter.controller;

import com.assistt.ivradapter.dto.WhatNextRequestDTO;
import com.assistt.ivradapter.dto.WhatNextResponseDTO;
import com.assistt.ivradapter.service.WhatNextService;
import com.assistt.ivradapter.util.SessionManager;
import org.jvoicexml.event.error.SemanticError;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.MDC;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class WhatNextController {

    

    @PostMapping("/whatNext")
    public WhatNextResponseDTO whatNext(@RequestParam String ___DDSESSIONID, @RequestBody WhatNextRequestDTO whatNextRequestDTO){
        WhatNextService whatNextService = new WhatNextService();
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WhatNextController.class);

        String final___DDSESSIONID = ___DDSESSIONID.replace(' ','+');
            WhatNextResponseDTO response = null;
            try {
                if(SessionManager.getInstance().getSession(final___DDSESSIONID) != null && SessionManager.getInstance().getSession(final___DDSESSIONID).getCurrentProcessOrder() != null){
                    MDC.put("session.id", String.format("%s - %s", final___DDSESSIONID, SessionManager.getInstance().getSession(final___DDSESSIONID).getCurrentProcessOrder().getDataModel().readVariable("session___ucid",String.class)));
                } else {
                    MDC.put("session.id", final___DDSESSIONID);
                }
                logger.info("entering WhatNextService-getResponseFromJboss.");
                response = whatNextService.getResponseFromJBoss(final___DDSESSIONID, whatNextRequestDTO.getNamelist());
                logger.info("returning /whatNext endpoint response : {}", response);
            } catch (Exception | SemanticError e) {
                logger.error("WhatNextController ERROR : {}", e.getMessage(), e);
            } finally {
                MDC.clear();
            }
            return response;
    }
}
```

However, on a server with one standalone.xml, requests return successfully.

If there is any setting you want to see, I can write it down.

I tried to add jboss-web.xml to WEB-INF/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
        <context-root>ivr-adapter-0.0.1</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

I still get same error.